# Convert row data into columns

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table that contains questions and answers within the rows eg

```
Name    | Question | Answer
Person1| Q1 | A1
Person1| Q2 | A2
Person1| Q3 | A3
Person2| Q1 | A1
Person2| Q2 | A2
Person2| Q3 | A3
```

[example of above table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn5u1.png)

I need my SQL query to return each individual person on a row and for the answers to be column headings and the answers populated within the row eg

```
|Name | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
Person1 | A1  |A2|  A3 
Person2 | A1  | A2| A3
```

[example of results table I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QzdS.png)

Any help or advice greatfully appreciated

Comment: which DBMS you use ? and I suggest you to research about PIVOT query result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when question = 'Q1' then answer end) as q1,
       max(case when question = 'Q2' then answer end) as q2,
       max(case when question = 'Q3' then answer end) as q3
from t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an example for your question=

```
CREATE table #yourtabl
    ([Name] varchar(10), [Question] varchar(10), [Answer] varchar(10))
;
    
INSERT INTO #yourtabl
    ([Name]  , [Question], [Answer])
VALUES
    ('Person1', 'Q1', 'A1'),
    ('Person1', 'Q2', 'A2'),
    ('Person1', 'Q3', 'A3'),
    ('Person2', 'Q1', 'A1'),
    ('Person2', 'Q2', 'A2'),
    ('Person2', 'Q3', 'A3')
    ;


SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        [Name], 
        [Question],
        [Answer]
    FROM 
        #yourtabl
) t 
PIVOT(
    max([Answer]) 
    FOR [Question] IN (
        [Q1], 
        [Q2], 
        [Q3]
        )
) AS pivot_table;
```

result =

```
Name    Q1  Q2  Q3
Person1 A1  A2  A3
Person2 A1  A2  A3
```